# bootstrap image gallery modal displays garbage character instead of image laravel 5.2

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-5

I am using the bootstrap image gallery to display my images, this is displayed using modal, and inside the modal when you click the image it will be open in yet another modal where you can see the original size of the image. The only problem here is that only first image is turned into garbage, the rest are all displaying properly.

Garbage or string information of image:

> GIF89a�%�������fff!��,�%��������p�
>   n�{v�E!�Y�����&������:3�`�@���.���+�T�Q����"������7q9�����ķ}f��nzܺx������ePb�E�c���W��@昇He&هɘE)y8��J�9�ɧ�'�(j   ���j��I�T{�ʚ(��[Y9;|�[hl+��������,�����\�;��=ݝ;��\j-NMn�]��Dtd�~S?�L�t�OW
>   3l|0�A�:|1�ĉ+Z��1��1� t�����F~4 #%
>   �%E���Q�A��y�J�'_����M�2c��y�(ҖB����N�?u"��4+T�Q�j��u�Ҝ>�}�*�(U�iۂ=[�פnѾ�w�ܰw������^�M|m*�Ì�"�n�\��7f+U�^ʏ[�S;

Code inside the controller where the content for the modal is generated:

```
$data[] = '<div class="panel panel-primary">';
                        $data[] = '<div class="panel-heading">';
                            $data[] = 'Attachments';
                        $data[] = '</div>';
                        $data[] = '<div class="panel-body">';
                            $data[] = '<div class="row">';
                                $attachemnt_img = DB::table('attachment')->where('session_id', $input)->get();
                                $data[] = '<div id="links">';
                                foreach($attachemnt_img as $img_url){
                                        $data[] = '<a href="uploads\images\\'.$img_url->url.'" title="Banana" data-gallery data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2">';
                                            $data[] = '<img src="uploads\images\\'.$img_url->url.'" width="20%" alt="Banana">';
                                        $data[] = '</a>';                                           
                                    $url = $img_url->url;
                                }           
                                $data[] = '</div>';
                            $data[] = '</div>';

                        $data[] = '</div>';
                        $data[] = '<div id="blueimp-gallery" class="blueimp-gallery">';
                                            $data[] = '<div class="slides"></div>';
                                            $data[] = '<h3 class="title"></h3>';
                                            $data[] = '<a class="prev">‹</a>';
                                            $data[] = '<a class="next">›</a>';
                                            $data[] = '<a class="close">×</a>';
                                            $data[] = '<a class="play-pause"></a>';
                                            $data[] = '<ol class="indicator"></ol>';
                                            $data[] = '<div id="myModal2" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">';
                                                $data[] = '<div class="modal-dialog">';
                                                    $data[] = '<div class="modal-content">';
                                                        $data[] = '<div class="modal-header">';
                                                            $data[] = '<button type="button" class="close" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>';
                                                            $data[] = '<h4 class="modal-title"></h4>';
                                                        $data[] = '</div>';
                                                        $data[] = '<div class="modal-body next"></div>';
                                                        $data[] = '<div class="modal-footer">';
                                                            $data[] = '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left prev">';
                                                                $data[] = '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i>';
                                                                $data[] = 'Previous';
                                                            $data[] = '</button>';
                                                            $data[] = '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary next">';
                                                                $data[] = 'Next';
                                                                $data[] = '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i>';
                                                            $data[] = '</button>';
                                                        $data[] = '</div>';
                                                    $data[] = '</div>';
                                                $data[] = '</div>';
                                            $data[] = '</div>';
                                $data[] = '</div>';
                    $data[] = '</div>';
```

my AJAX:

```
function viewModal(id){
            var mystring, stringie;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: baseUrl + '/modalView',
                data: {id:id, "_token": token},
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data){
                    stringie = data.toString();
                    mystring = stringie.replace(/[,]/g, '');
                   $(".modal-content").html(mystring);
                },
                statusCode: {
                    500: function() {
                    },
                    422: function(data) {
                        // 
                    }
                }
            }); 
        }
```

Modal in view:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade " tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" style="max-width: 1300px;">
            <div class="modal-content">

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Take a look at this github [issue](https://github.com/Intervention/image/issues/72). Laravel 4 is used here but the approach to resolve can be the same.